# Java Preferences for each user in HKEY_USERS

Tags: java, preferences

I'm using Preferences.userRoot() to create keys for individual users.

On uninstall, I'm calling the Jar file to remove all of the created keys.  I'd like to remove all of the keys for each user.  Right now I can only remove them for the Default user during the uninstall since userRoot() returns the preferences for the calling user.

Is it possible to iterate over all the users in HKEY_USERS and create a preferences object for each one?

Comment: possible? YES ANY-THING, IS POSSBLE

Comment: Sure... then I suppose the real question is how